# Merging data from Tables with different schema

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

For a report we need to merge 2 SQL Server database tables of different schemas. I have tried

```
SELECT ControlRec FROM MercerReportTable
UNION
SELECT * FROM MercerReportTableMod 
ORDER BY orderby ASC
```

but this and JOINs cause the following error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I assume this means it won't merge because the tables are different.

There must be a way; can anyone please help? I did a search here on merging tables but the posts didn't help me.

Thanks!

Comment: When you do a UNION all SELECTs must have the same number of columns

Comment: If you have a different number of columns between tables, but you want to select across all tables with UNION, then the output of each SELECT statement must have the same number of columns.  For any columns that don't exist in certain tables, you'll need to define a value that will be output for that column - it might just be a Null, or a hard-coded value, or a concatenation of other columns in the table .... for example SELECT col1, col2, Null FROM table 1 UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2.  Simple example, but the "Null" selected from "table1" aligns with "col3" from "table2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
> have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

This is because your count of columns aren't same, when you using the following SQL.

```
SELECT ControlRec
FROM MercerReportTable
UNION
SELECT *
FROM MercerReportTableMod
ORDER BY orderby ASC
```

Please try something like:

```
SELECT ControlRec
FROM MercerReportTable
UNION
SELECT ControlRec
FROM MercerReportTableMod
ORDER BY orderby ASC
```

**Edit:**

The other way is to specify empty columns to match the number of columns in other tables, notice the default empty strings/varchars '' and default integers, bits & dates eg:

```
SELECT ControlRec, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '2021/03/29', ''
FROM MercerReportTable
UNION
SELECT *
FROM MercerReportTableMod
ORDER BY orderby ASC
```

Comment: You may well prefer `UNION ALL` as `UNION` de-duplicates the data, at a performance cost.